# What is the difference between mdl and div element in HTML and Material Design Lite?

Tags: css, html, attributes, material-design, element

***What is the difference between mdl and div element?***

*I have used the two interchangeably.*

*Is there a speed advantage to either one?*

**For example:**

I can use...

```
<mdl class="mdl-grid">
  <mdl class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp">
    1
  </mdl>
</mdl>
```

Or use...

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--6dp">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mdl` is not a valid HTML5 element but a `div` is and because of this, `div`s are faster.

Source: https://validator.w3.org/ - Type in the code and swap div with mdl. (MDL=2 milliseconds, div = 1 millisecond)